# How to use API gateway to call another service running on an EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a confusing scenario. I am new to AWS. I have some available services written in java jersy and I have them deployed on an Ec2 instance.

I am asked to use API gateway to call these services rather than calling them directly. So for instance if I have a service as follows:

```
http://domainname/article/2
```

I want the front end to first call the following endpoint of API gateway:

```
https://my-api-id.execute-api.region-id.amazonaws.com/stage-name/article
```

and then the above API Gateway end point call the my service.
What I am thinking is there is a http proxy in integration type when I try to create the API gateway resource. I assume this can fit my purpose but I am not sure about it and I am totally confused.

Can anyone shed light on how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the API Gateway Console, create a resource (eg. /v1/user/info) and method (eg. GET/POST etc).

Select **Integration Request**

[image]

You can then configure a **an HTTP Proxy** or a Lambda function any other AWS Resource. In your case, you want this to be pointing to your EC2 hosted URL.

[image]